# Common table expression,WITH clause in PostgreSQL ;ERROR: relation "stkpos" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

for example the following is my query

```
WITH stkpos as (
select * from mytbl
),
updt as (
update stkpos set field=(select sum(fieldn) from stkpos)
)
select * from stkpos
```

> ERROR:  relation "stkpos" does not exist

Comment: Well, you cannot update the results of the query. And CTE is a named sub-query, that exists only for the duration of your statement.

Comment: Why are you using a CTE in the first place? `update mytbl set field=(select sum(fieldn) from mytbl)` should work just fine (although it does not make any sense for me)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  this is not my actual query, its so complicated and a long query

Comment: Maybe you want to get `sum(fieldn)` as another column in `stkpos`? Something like `with stkpos(select *, sum(fieldn) over() from mytbl) select * from stkpos`?

Answer (score 3):

Unlike MS-SQL and some other DBs, PostgreSQL's CTE terms are not treated like a view. They're more like an implicit temp table - they get materialized, the planner can't push filters down into them or pull filters up out of them, etc.

One consequence of this is that you can't update them, because they're a *copy* of the original data, not just a view of it. You'll need to find another way to do what you want.

If you want help with that you'll need to post a new question that has a clear and self contained example (with `create table` statements, etc) showing a cut down version of your real problem. Enough to actually let us understand what you're trying to accomplish and why.